# Upgrade Version Client of Elasticsearch in jHipster Project

Tags: jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

Im use a Elasticsearch 5.1.2 (docker installation) and integrated with a project generated with jHipster 4.0.2.

After configure Elasticsearch, Elastic show the message:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.1.2]
sn_elasticsearch  |**

Its posible to upgrade the client version of Spring Data Elastic integration in jHipster project? Someone knows how to?

[]s

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-elasticsearch does not support version 5 yet.  It is a work in progress by a team of volunteers (not driven by the Spring Data team).

According to the [latest post on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/170#issuecomment-277205567) where you can track the issue:

> Given that we will look into upgrading elasticsearch to latest version and as @olivergierke suggested it will be released with Kay if we will be able to merge changes before RC1 which is in mid March [2017].
>
> This pull request still require major week or two of a work, its not straight forward merge. We are independent resource(s) willing to contribute on this project wherever we can, anyone who is willing to do the same is more than welcome to contribute.
>
> We will keep posting update from our side about upgrade on the same thread.